# Sticky left sidebar shrink & right side bar expand when reached top edge of browser

Tags: html, css

Good day, I need a little coding help, I just put a simple sticky blogger code on my blog. It's working nice but there's just one thing need to be fix. When the sidebars reached the top browser edge the left shrinks a bit and the right expand next to the scroll bar. What changes should I do to make the two sidebars remain the same up to the edge. Below is the code I used in my blogger blog.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    var ks_widget_top = $('#widget Id').offset().top;
    var ks_sticky_widgets = function(){
        var ks_current_top = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        if (ks_current_top > ks_widget_top) { 
          $('#widget Id').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'z-index':999999 });
        } else {
            $('#widget Id').css({ 'position': 'relative' }); 
        }   
    };
    ks_sticky_widgets();
      $(window).scroll(function() {
         ks_sticky_widgets();
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: `#widget Id` seems to be an invalid id.  It's also unclear what your problem is when you only show jquery code for one element and you talk about 2.  Please can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: Can u add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I used the #sidebar-right-1 #sidebar-left-1 id..

Comment: Hello sir, i'm still trying to add some widgets on my new blog. This is my url 
https://nostalgiatrain.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] like we have asked you to

Comment: What I did sir I only add the #sidebar-right-1 & #sidebar-left-1, replaced the #widget id on the jquery. This is my blogger url https://nostalgiatrain.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the code of your blog. Seems that instead of changing the position of the `#sidebar-right-1` use `.main-inner.column-left-outer`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    var ks_widget_top = $('#widget Id').offset().top;
    var ks_sticky_widgets = function(){
        var ks_current_top = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        if (ks_current_top > ks_widget_top) { 
          $('.main-inner.column-left-outer').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'right': 'auto', 'z-index':999999 });
        } else {
            $('.main-inner.column-left-outer').css({ 'position': 'relative' }); 
        }   
    };
    ks_sticky_widgets();
      $(window).scroll(function() {
         ks_sticky_widgets();
    });
});</script>
```

Just let me know if this works